# Parabolic Interpolation

Tags: interpolation

I'm reading this lecture page:
http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e176/lectures/NM/node25.html
and towards the end of the discussion, it says that upon finding $x_{min}$, the process can be repeated using a new set of points by eliminating one of the old ones. Is this essentially what successive parabolic interpolation is? Or is there a subtlety involved? Also, how do I generate $f(x_{min})$? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a kind [dichotomy method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method) by successive parabolic interpolation.

At each step we find a new set of three points which gives a better approximation for the minimum (or maximum).

Comment: Thanks. Any idea on how $f(x_{min})$ is calculated using parabolic interpolation?

Comment: Given the three points around the minimum(maximum) we approximate the function by $q(x)$ and then we find the miimum(maximum) by the condition on the derivative $q'(x)=0$.